# Best approach how to convert user from non authed to to authed when using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on the application using Firebase Realtime database. App is live but I see problem with users that they don't want to login (so I'm losing a lot of users because one of first screens is login screen).

I'm thinking to update my app to be able to work without login and when user decides to authenticate then I would send his/her data into cloud and continue working as usually.

What is (on your opinion) best approach? Should I create JSON nodes something like `sessions_unauthed` with random uuis for not logged users and `sessions` for logged users. And move data from one subtree to another when user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is that you can use anonymous login function of firebase and storing that uid to sharedpreferences and then moving those nodes to the newly logged in user's uid nodes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome. It looks like exactly was I was looking for. Just linking doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth in case anybody would be also interested.